# Problema con QUERY retorna VACÍO y no puedo verificar - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo un problema con respecto a la validación de una query que me retorna vacío:

```sql
select UnidadMedida
from MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni 
 join MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir on uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
where mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' and mir.NroProducto = 472
```

Esto me retorna, lo cuál está bien porque no hay nada en ese `WHERE`:

```sql
+--------------+
| UnidadMedida |
+--------------+
|              |
+--------------+
```

Sin embargo, ahora cuando quiero validar ese vacío lo hago de estas maneras:

```sql
select iif(LEN(UnidadMedida) = 0 
       OR DATALENGTH(UnidadMedida) = 0 
       OR UnidadMedida = '',1,UnidadMedida) UnidadMedida
from MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni 
 join MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir on uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
where mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' and mir.NroProducto = 472
```

```sql
select ISNULL(UnidadMedida,1) UnidadMedida
from MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni 
 join MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir on uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
where mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' and mir.NroProducto = 472
```

Y el retorno es el mismo:

```sql
+--------------+
| UnidadMedida |
+--------------+
|              |
+--------------+
```

La respuesta esperada sería:

```sql
+--------------+
| UnidadMedida |
+--------------+
| 1            |
+--------------+
```

Cabe mencionar que el tipo de columna es <kbd>**INT**</kbd>

---

**Update:**

[image: 1]

Comment: ¿Regresa nulo, una cadena vacía o no regresa filas?

Comment: No regresa filas. Coloqué imagen.

Comment: Si no regresa filas, es ilógico que cambiando la expresión de la lista de columnas aparezca una fila.

Comment: Qué se pueden hacer en esos casos? Lo que deseo es traer un resultado por defecto en caso no haya filas, que sería 1.

Comment: Cuáles son los datos de prueba en las tablas involucradas para los que podríamos probar tu consulta y ayudarte a corregirla? Cualquier consulta con sintaxis correcta es una consulta válida, sólo que traerá datos diferentes... el punto es ver qué datos intentas poner en la proyección. Ve a [edit] e incluye esos datos de prueba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes que validar que se regresen filas, puedes usar varias opciones.

Opción 1: Usar variables

```
DECLARE @UnidadMedida int = 1;

SELECT @UnidadMedida = UnidadMedida
FROM MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni
JOIN MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir ON uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
WHERE mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' 
AND   mir.NroProducto = 472;

SELECT @UnidadMedida AS UnidadMedida;
```

Opción 1b: Usar variable con `ISNULL`

```
SELECT @UnidadMedida = ISNULL( (SELECT UnidadMedida
                                FROM MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni
                                JOIN MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir ON uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
                                WHERE mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' 
                                AND   mir.NroProducto = 472), 1);
```

Opción 2: Usar `IF EXISTS`

```
IF EXISTS(  SELECT UnidadMedida
            FROM MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni
            JOIN MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir ON uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
            WHERE mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' 
            AND   mir.NroProducto = 472)
    SELECT UnidadMedida
    FROM MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni
    JOIN MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir ON uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
    WHERE mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' 
    AND   mir.NroProducto = 472
ELSE
    SELECT 1 AS UnidadMedida;
```

Opción 3: Usar `UNION ALL` y `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT UnidadMedida
FROM MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni
JOIN MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir ON uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
WHERE mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' 
AND   mir.NroProducto = 472
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS UnidadMedida
WHERE NOT EXISTS(  SELECT UnidadMedida
                    FROM MM_UNIDAD_MEDIDA uni
                    JOIN MAN_InventarioRepuestos mir ON uni.Nombre = mir.DescUnidadMedida
                    WHERE mir.CodAlmacen = 'a1' 
                    AND   mir.NroProducto = 472);
```

Comment: Para mi conveniencia la opción 1b fue la adecuada, muchas gracias!